# How to update rows using nested queries

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery

I have a table where the date of birth is 0000-00-00 where the format is YYYY-MM-DD. I have given the task to update these date to real DOB.

The DOB can only be extracted from the Identification Number which looks like `950313094353` (Not a real IC number) and IC is created like `YYMMDDSNRAND` where `SN` is state number e.g 09 and `RAND` is just 4 random numbers e.g 4353.

From the IC number, I can get the date of birth by substring the first 6 digits.

**The table**

```
student_st
IC_NO         D_BIRTH     COUNTRY
------------  ----------  --------
940525053455  0000-00-00  MALAYSIA
```

The datatype of IC_NO is varchar, D_BIRTH is date and COUNTRY is varchar

**My code that I tried is**

```
UPDATE `student_st`
SET `D_BIRTH` =  CONCAT('19', (SELECT SUBSTR(`IC_NO`, 1, 2) FROM `student_st` WHERE `COUNTRY`='MALAYSIA'),
                 '-', (SELECT SUBSTR(`IC_NO`, 3, 2) FROM `student_st` WHERE `COUNTRY`='MALAYSIA'),
                 '-', (SELECT SUBSTR(`IC_NO`, 5, 2) FROM `student_st` WHERE `COUNTRY`='MALAYSIA')) 
WHERE `COUNTRY`='MALAYSIA' AND DATE(`D_BIRTH`)='0000-00-00'
```

**This is the error that I'm getting**

```
Error in query (1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '0000-00-00'
```

I don't know why the error is stating this.

From my code, the result that I expected is `19YY-MM-DD` where YY, MM and DD obtained from substring the IC number.

Comment: 'MALAYSIA' Backticks should be quotes.please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. Now I'm getting the error `Error in query (1292): Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'D_BIRTH' at row 1`. I changed the backtick in D_BIRTH too

Comment: what datatype is d_birth

Comment: The datatype for D_BIRTH is date NULL. I tried DATE(D_BIRTH) = 0000-00-00 but it says `Error in query (1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '0000-00-00'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all those selects in sub queries an update is a row by row update.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(IC_NO  varchar(20),       D_BIRTH  date, country varchar(20));
insert into t values
(940525053455 , '0000-00-00','malasia'),
(960525053455 , '1995-05-25','malasia'),
(940525053455 , '0000-00-00','aa');

update t
        set d_birth = str_to_date(concat('19',SUBSTR(`IC_NO`, 1, 2),SUBSTR(`IC_NO`, 3, 2) ,SUBSTR(`IC_NO`, 5, 2)),'%Y%m%d')
where country = 'malasia' and d_birth = '0000-00-00'
;

select * from t;

+--------------+------------+---------+
| IC_NO        | D_BIRTH    | country |
+--------------+------------+---------+
| 940525053455 | 1994-05-25 | malasia |
| 960525053455 | 1995-05-25 | malasia |
| 940525053455 | 0000-00-00 | aa      |
+--------------+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I followed your code at the UPDATE part and I'm getting this error `Error in query (1292): Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'D_BIRTH' at row 1`. I tried DATE(D_BIRTH) = 0000-00-00 but then it says `Error in query (1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '0000-00-00'`

Comment: nvm it is just my SQL version preventing this. THANK YOU SO MUCH :)